# Retrieve failure message when sending email to non-existent address

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am sending mail to "ksjdcbnjkhbvsmdbsdb@gmail.com" (a non-existent email) using my code below. Because that email address does not exist, the email should have been bounced back. I want to get the failure message, but my code does not print this failure message. What is the problem here, and how should I get the failure message?

```
import smtplib
import email
import imaplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def processNewTripData(request):
    # process trip data
    templateName = "sendmail.html"
    mapDictionary = {'fromMail': "xxx@gmail.com", 'password': "xxxx", 'toMail':    "ksjdcbnjkhbvsmdbsdb@gmail.com","subject": "New Trip ", 'username': 'Ram','trip_start_date' : '2014-02-10','trip_start_place' : 'Visaka', 'trip_start_time' : '11:00 AM', "templateName" : templateName }
    return sendMail(request, mapDictionary)


def sendMail(request, mapDictionary):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(mapDictionary["fromMail"],mapDictionary["password"])
        context = Context(mapDictionary)
        html_content = render_to_string(mapDictionary["templateName"], context)   
        #text_content = "This is Confirmation mail"       
        msg = MIMEText(html_content,'html')
        msg['Subject'] = mapDictionary["subject"]

        server.sendmail(mapDictionary["fromMail"], mapDictionary['toMail'],msg.as_string())

        if (msg.is_multipart() and len(msg.get_payload()) > 1 and msg.get_payload(1).get_content_type() == 'message/delivery-status'):
        # email is DSN
        print(msg.get_payload(0).get_payload()) # human-readable section
        for dsn in msg.get_payload(1).get_payload():
            print('action: %s' % dsn['action']) # e.g., "failed", "delivered"

        to_json = {'result' : "True"}


    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
        to_json = {'result' : "False"}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that the failure will be reported while your session is open.  SMTP is fundamentally a store-and-forward protocol; you should expect the message to be handled by a relay which does not know whether or not the final destination is reachable.  Even if you are connecting directly to Google's designated MX, they may have internal routing in place which works exactly like this.  Some domains also put off reporting errors in order to slow down spammers (attempting to deliver would be a good way to check which addresses are valid otherwise.  In fact, what you are doing probably looks to Google like you are a newbie spammer, so they could have put your IP address in a list of hosts to give "special" treatment).

Comment: The only way to handle this with even an approximation to accuracy is to set a Reply-To header so that any bounce messages can be processed by a separate program. Having implemented logic to read the messages and handle error messages in various formats from various SMTP servers in the past I know that not all servers will bother to action the Reply-To header when raising error messages, and some are configured not to raise bounce messages at all. In my project there was credit card fraud potential. So the more bounces we could catch the less we were defrauded and it was worth implementing.